# Railroad train on tracks

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, stability, applied-physics

What keeps the railroad trains on the tracks?

P.S: It is not the flanges, as already remarked by Dr. Richard Feynman.

I want a detailed explanation of this question, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: It is actually a pretty good question, but, I couldn't get the explanation for it. Friction is not actually the answer.

Comment: Welcome to PSE and apologies for downvoting, but you need to show a bit of your own research. Something like this : https://www.quora.com/What-keeps-a-train-on-its-tracks, then you can ask for any points you don't follow in this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface of the track is slightly curved and the wheels are tapered or conical so that they centre themselves between the tracks.

The larger diameter of the cone is on the inside.

See [this on wikipedia for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_wheel)